# flutter_bloc - How to keep variables in memory between screens

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

I'm using flutter_bloc for handling state in my Flutter App. I'm using Firestore as storage.

**My question:**

1. What is the best way to store temporary variables, and keep them
   available throughout screens?
2. Is it intended, that if I want to
   build firestore queries with nested collections, that I need to pass
   the document id's through the bloc and the repository, to build the queries?

As in my case I need to store the id's, to be able to build firestore queries with nested collections in documents.

I have following structure in firestore:

```
school (document)
  - courses (collection)
    - course1 (document)
    - course2 (document)
    - ...
      - sections (collection)
        - ...
```

Queries:

To get the courses:

```
Firestore.instance
  .collection('schools')
  .document('<school id>')
  .collection("courses")
  .snapshots();
```

To get the sections to a course:

```
Firestore.instance
  .collection('schools')
  .document('<school id>')
  .collection('courses')
  .document('<course id>')
  .collection('sections')
  .snapshots();
```

So I need to somehow persist the "school id" and the "course id" and pass them down the bloc and repository, to build the firestore query.

At the moment my bloc function that is loading the school, will load it from firestore, and then persist it serialized in shared_preferences.

The function that reads the school, will read it from shared_preferences, instead of firestore after that. So I can access shared_preferences from another screen, when I need the data. But somehow this feels a little bit messy. I've looked at hydrated_bloc, which basically does the same, so I might use that but it still feels messy having to pass down the variables through the bloc and repository to build the query.

I'm a beginner when it comes to creating a good architecture with bloc, and I'd prefer to build something proper from the beginning.

Does anybody know a better way of doing this?

Here my repository class. As you can see, I need to parse the school document id to the firebase repository. At the moment it's hard coded.

```
class FirebaseCourseRepository implements CourseRepository {
  final courseCollection = Firestore.instance
    .collection('school')
    .document("3kRHuyk20UggHwm4wrUI") // this is where I need to pass the doc id from the bloc to.
    .collection("course");

  @override
  Stream<List<Course>> courses() {
    return courseCollection.snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents
          .map((doc) => Course.fromEntity(CourseEntity.fromSnapshot(doc)))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> addCourse(Course course) {
    return courseCollection.add(course.toEntity().toDocument());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> updateCourse(Course updatedCourse) {
    return courseCollection
        .document(updatedCourse.id)
        .updateData(updatedCourse.toEntity().toDocument());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> deleteCourse(Course course) async {
    return courseCollection.document(course.id).delete();
  }  
}
```

And here the bloc. I don't really know, how I can pass the document id to the repository only once.

```
class CourseBloc extends Bloc<CourseEvent, CourseState> {
  final CourseRepository _courseRepository;
  StreamSubscription _courseSubscription;

  // Repository is injected through constructor, so that it can
  // be easily tested.
  CourseBloc({@required CourseRepository courseRepository})
      : assert(courseRepository != null),
        _courseRepository = courseRepository;

  @override
  get initialState => CourseInitState();

  @override
  Stream<CourseState> mapEventToState(CourseEvent event) async* {
    if(event is LoadCoursesEvent) {
      yield* _mapLoadCoursesToState(event);
    } else if(event is CoursesLoadedEvent) {
      yield* _mapCoursesLoadedToState(event);
    } else if(event is AddCourseEvent) {
      yield* _mapAddCourseToState(event);
    } else if(event is UpdateCourseEvent) {
      yield* _mapUpdateCourseToState(event);
    } else if(event is DeleteCourseEvent) {
      yield* _mapDeleteCourseToState(event);
    }
  }

  // Load all courses
  Stream<CourseState> _mapLoadCoursesToState(LoadCoursesEvent event) async* {
    yield CoursesLoadingState();
    _courseSubscription?.cancel();
    _courseSubscription = _courseRepository.courses().listen(
      (courses) {
        dispatch(
          CoursesLoadedEvent(courses),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Stream<CourseState> _mapCoursesLoadedToState(CoursesLoadedEvent event) async* {
    yield CoursesLoadedState(event.courses);
  }

  Stream<CourseState> _mapAddCourseToState(AddCourseEvent event) async* {
    _courseRepository.addCourse(event.course);
  }

  Stream<CourseState> _mapUpdateCourseToState(UpdateCourseEvent event) async* {
    _courseRepository.updateCourse(event.updatedCourse);
  }  

  Stream<CourseState> _mapDeleteCourseToState(DeleteCourseEvent event) async* {
    _courseRepository.deleteCourse(event.course);
  }  

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _courseSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no one right way to do that. 
But in general I would rather keep repositories stateless. What you can do is to introduce parent bloc which loads ID from some repository and child blocs depend on the parent bloc to provide ID. 
Please take a look at Todos example in the official documentation. https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial

Comment: Thanks Filip, that's an interesting suggestion. Are you referring to Bloc to Bloc Communication when talking about parent and child blocs? https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication

Comment: I have decided to create a repository for shared_preferences and will inject the repository into the BLOCS where I need them. So I might have more than one repository, that I inject into the BLOC.I will have a SharedStoreRepository with getString and setString methods. If at some point, I don't want to use shared_preferences but sembast, I can just exchange the repository. I think this way the code stays decoupled, and testable. I don't know if this is best practice, but as the documentation leaves this point open, I guess that's my way to go.

Comment: Ok, it actually is documented and I need new glasses... The bloc layer can depend on one or more repositories to retrieve data needed to build up the application state.